# How do I get Tailwind CSS to work with VueJS and Docker

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, tailwind-css

I have a VueJS with Tailwind app that runs fine with `npm run dev`, but when I Dockerise it, the CSS cannot be found.

This a simplified view of the folder structure

```
runplan/
│
└───dist/
│   [build files, inc assets]       
│   output.csv
│   
└───node_modules/
│   
└───src/
│   input.css
│   
│Dockerfile
│nginx.conf
│package.json
│tailwind.config.js
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY ./nginx.conf /app/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This is the nginx configuration

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
      root   /app;
      index  index.html;
      try_files $uri  /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
```

I've played around with loads of tweaks to the Dockerfile.

Any help in getting the CSS loaded is appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you please add above code into a reproducible Git repository? So that we can run it locally to fix the issues?

Comment: Hey. I realised that it was postcss that was answer the my predicament.